# Update specific object in array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a DataTable and an array of objects that I loop through.

For each row in a data table, I search through my collection of objects with Linq, and if found, that object needs to be updated.
But how do I refresh my collection without reloading it from the database?

```
Car[] mycars = Cars.RetrieveCars(); //This is my collection of objects

//Iterate through Cars and find a match 
using (DataTable dt = data.ExecuteDataSet(@"SELECT * FROM aTable").Tables[0])
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) //Iterate through Data Table 
         {
            var found = (from item in mycars 
                         where item.colour == dr["colour"].ToString()
                            && item.updated == false
                         select item).First();
             if (found == null)
                //Do something
             else
             {
                  found.updated = true;
                  Cars.SaveCar(found);
                  //HERE: Now here I would like to refresh my collection (mycars) so that the LINQ searches on updated data.
                  //Something like mycars[found].updated = true
                  //But obviously mycars can only accept int, and preferably I do not want to reload from the database for performance reasons.
             }
```

How else can I search and update a single item in the array?

Comment: As an aside, I think you mean `if (found == null)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to update your collection - assuming `Car` is a class, you've already updated the object that the array refers to by setting `found.updated` to `true`.

Don't forget that the array only contains *references* - so the `found` reference is the same reference which is in the array; updating the object via either variable will result in the change being visible via the other one.

Comment: References you say.  Interesting.  Will test it.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1208908: Yes. This is part of the *core* of C# - it's really important that you understand how objects and references work in C#. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html